# Tweepy streaming behind proxy not working

Tags: python, proxy, tweepy

I can't seem to get tweepy stream working behind a proxy. By this I mean I've tried doing this:

```
tweepy.API(auth, proxy = "1.1.1.1:8080")
```

I used that exact same address which clearly isn't valid, and tweepy didn't give me any errors and just streamed normally, which is weird.

I've looked at other similar questions relating to this and none seem to work or have valuable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Couldn't be fucked to look through the whole of tweepy, but for some reason, the proxy setting wasn't being passed to the streaming function/wasn't working correctly.

I fixed this by adding a manual proxy configuration in line 225 of streaming.py in the tweepy lib, such as:

```
self.session.proxies = {'https': '1.1.1.1:8080'}
```

Although this is quite a hackish manual way to solve it, it works. I'll fix it properly at some time in the future.